# when were index statistics last updated?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2005

Is there a quick and easy way to list when every index in the database last had their statistics updated?  The preferred answer would be a query.  Also, is it possible to determine the "quality" of the statistics: FULLSCAN, SAMPLE n, etc.

**EDIT**
This worked for what I needed, a slight mod to @OrbMan great answer...

```
SELECT
    STATS_DATE(i.object_id, i.index_id) AS LastStatisticsDate
        ,o.Name AS TableName
        ,i.name AS IndexName
    FROM sys.objects            o
        INNER JOIN sys.indexes  i ON o.object_id = i.object_id
    WHERE o.is_ms_shipped=0
    ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do: STATS_DATE ( table_id , index_id )

So:

```
USE AdventureWorks;
GO
SELECT 'Index Name' = i.name, 'Statistics Date' = STATS_DATE(i.object_id, i.index_id)
FROM sys.objects o
JOIN sys.indexes i ON o.name = 'Address' AND o.object_id = i.object_id;
GO
```

where Address is the name of the table whose indexes you would like to examine.